# Need to add query tag to snowflake queries while I fetch data from python ( using threadpool, code is provided)

Tags: sql, python-3.x, multithreading, threadpool, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using SQLAlchemy by create engine to connect python to snowflake for fetching data. Adding a snippet of code on how I am doing it. Before you suggest to use connector.snowflake, I have tried that and it has query tag but I need to pull queries by thread pool method and couldn't find a way to add query tag.

Have also tried ALTER SESSION SET QUERY_TAG but since the query runs parallelly it doesn't give the query tag.

Code:

```
vendor_class_query ='select * from table' 
query_list1 = [vendor_class_query]
pool = ThreadPool(8)

def query(x):
engine = create_engine(
    'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/{database_name}/{schema_name}?\
    warehouse={warehouse}&role={role}&paramstyle={paramstyle}'.format(
        user=---------,
        password=----------,
        account=----------,
        database_name=----------,
        schema_name=----------,
        warehouse=----------,
        role=----------,
        paramstyle='pyformat'
        
    ),
    poolclass=NullPool
)
try:
    connection = engine.connect()
    for df in pd.read_sql_query(x, engine, chunksize=1000000000):
        df.columns = map(str.upper, df.columns)
        return df
finally:
    connection.close()
    engine.dispose()
return df

results1 = pool.map(query, query_list1)
vendor_class = results1[0]'''
```

Comment: what is it you're trying to do with the query_tag?  I'm mainly interested in whether you are trying to apply a unique query_tag for each execution, each connection, or at the the engine creation.

Comment: Hey Mike, I want to apply query tag at the engine creation.

Comment: Do you want to dynamically set the query tag to a different value every time you run this or do you want to tag all queries run through this process with the same value (static tag)? If you want to use a static tag you could set up a user for just this process and set their default query tag: alter user xxxx set QUERY_TAG = 'Query Tag Text';

Answer (score 0):

You can add a query tag to the SQLAlchemy during create_engine as detailed here https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/issues/266

```
engine = create_engine(
    url=URL(
        account='my_snowflake_account',
        user='user_1',
        password="something1?",
        database="app_1",
        warehouse="app_1",
        role="dev",
    ),
    connect_args=dict(
        session_parameters=dict(
            timezone='America/Toronto',
            query_tag='test',
        )
    )
)
```